# ipod touch 4g is unable to play music on docking station

Tags: ipod-touch, ipod

I am not sure how to word this or even if there is an answer.
I have a iPod Touch 4th generation that I upgraded to 5.1.1 last week. Since then I have not been able to play tunes through my docking station. It 'sees' the song and I can see the play count but there is no volume/song heard.

I can put my daughters 2nd generation iPod Touch on and it works fine so I know it isn't the docking station that is the problem.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem but found it wouldn't work when the iPod had its cover on,  as soon as we removed the cover it worked fine. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the Dock adapter, the one that goes into the docking station that makes the dock fits iPod?

It could very likely be a connection problem, I had the same problem before.